# How to stop kubectl proxy

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I executed below command:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8081 &
kubectl proxy --port=8082 &
```

and of course I have 2 accessible endpoints:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/api/
curl http://localhost:8082/api/
```

But in the same time two running processes serving the same content.
How to stop one of these processes in "kubectl" manner? 
Of course, I can kill the process but it seems to be a less elegant way...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe the "kubectl way" is to not background the proxy at all as it is intended to be a short running process to access the API on your local machine without further authentication.

There is no way to stop it other than kill or ^C (if not in background).

You can use standard shell tricks though, so executing `fg` then ^C will work or `kill %1`

Comment: ^C didn't kill the process for me :\

Answer (score 17):

Run this command to figure out the process id (pid):

```
netstat -tulp | grep kubectl
```

Then run `sudo kill -9 <pid>` to kill the process.

Comment: ist must be `netstat` not `netsat`

Answer (score 11):

```sh
ps -ef | grep "kubectl proxy"
```

will show you the PID of the process

Then you can stop it with

```sh
kill -9 <pid>
```

Comment: kill is always an option

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the platform you could wrap the proxy in service / daemon, but seems like overkill I would just add aliases or functions to start and source them in your terminal/shell profile to make it easier.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

or

```
kubectl-proxy-start() {
    kubectl proxy &
}

kubectl-proxy-kill() {
    pkill -9 -f "kubectl proxy"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me in the MacOS

`pkill -9 -f "kubectl proxy"`

Answer (score 2):

Filter (grep) all "kube" pids and kill with loop:

```
for pid in `netstat -tulp | grep kube | awk '{print $7}' | awk -F"/" '{print $1}'| uniq`
 do
   kill -9 $pid
 done
```

Comment: kill is always an option

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using your port #s of course

```
$ pkill -f 'kubectl proxy --port=8080'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, to stop the background job in Powershell, it is:

```
get-job
Stop-Job Job1
```